# PHP Curl request blocked but works in browser

Tags: php, http, curl, web-scraping

I have a script that does some web scraping from a website. That website requires an OPTIONS request first and then a POST request that results in a json returned with the data I need. It was working fine, I ran it only like 6 or 7 times, the results were ok, but now my POST request results in a HTML page that says *"Your access to our site is blocked. Our site is using a security service to protect against attacks. Your access is triggering one of our security measures."*

I know they haven't blocked my IP because I can access the same site through the browser using the same IP and it works fine. So how do they know I'm using curl and not a real browser?

As you can see in my code below, I've changed the user-agent to match the one in my browser, I'm sending the exact same headers my browser sends.

```
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36';

$headerOptions = array(
    ':authority: flight-pricing.maxmilhas.com.br',
    ':method: OPTIONS',
    ':path: /search?time='.$epochtime,
    ':scheme: https',
    'accept: */*',
    'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type',
    'access-control-request-method: POST',
    'origin: https://www.maxmilhas.com.br',
    'user-agent: '.$useragent
);

$url = 'https://flight-pricing.maxmilhas.com.br/search?time='.$epochtime;

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/wamp64/www/maxmilhas/tmp/cookieoptions.txt");
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "OPTIONS",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headerOptions  
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_errno($curl);
    file_put_contents('log/headerout/options.txt',curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ));

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL -OPTIONS Request- Error #:" . $err;
}

file_put_contents('log/options.txt',$response);

$headerPost = array(
    ':authority: flight-pricing.maxmilhas.com.br',
    ':method: POST',
    ':path: /search?time='.$epochtime,
    ':scheme: https',
    'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'authorization: '.$authorization,
    'content-length: 145',
    'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin: https://www.maxmilhas.com.br',
    'referer: '.$refererPost,
    'user-agent: '.$useragent
);

$curl2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent );
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refererPost);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/wamp64/www/maxmilhas/tmp/cookiepost.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headerPost
    ));

    $response2 = curl_exec($curl2);
    $err2 = curl_errno($curl2);
    file_put_contents('log/headerout/post.txt',curl_getinfo($curl2, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ));

curl_close($curl2);

if ($err2) {
    echo "cURL -POST Request- Error #:" . $err2;
}

file_put_contents('log/post.txt',$response2);
```

So, I am copying the exact same requests sent by Google Chrome, as you can see in the pics below:

[Pic1: OPTIONS Request by Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6RoN.png)

[Pic2: POST request by Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwZOg.png)

The first time I was blocked, I wasn't using the COOKIEJAR option yet, so I figured that could be the issue. I enabled it, but still blocked.

So I know my code works fine because it was working great before the block and even before enabling cookies at all. I haven't changed anything since then. But it just seems that they can identify that this request comes from curl and then they block it.

So my question is: How are they blocking me if it's not through my IP? What differs my curl request from a normal browser request?

My bet is that this has to do with the cookies, but I have no clue on how to handle this issue other than enabling the COOKIEJAR option on the curl request.

Both of my cookie files are like this:

[Pic3: Cookie Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESUVS.png)

Thanks.

Comment: _"But it just seems that they can identify that this request comes from curl"_ - The server won't know if you used cURL or some other http client. If they block you, it probably means that they don't want you to scrape the site in the first place and trying to bypass their security is most likely against their TOS. SO is not the correct place to ask how to bypass a sites security protocols.

Comment: I'm not trying to bypass security protocols. I'm just trying to understand how a specific website can identify that my request is different than a browser. I used this website as an example, but my question is not site's specific, I could ask this related to any other website. The data I'm getting here is the same one I would get through a normal browser request, nothing illegal or against TOS, I just want to learn how to properly do it on PHP cURL.

Comment: Some sites go to a lot of trouble to block requests not coming from browsers. They have identified your request as a bot, which they don't want. You can still "fool" the site obviously if your http request is an exact duplicate of  a browser request, but obviously you have not achieved that yet despite your efforts. Try on different sites.

Comment: Also you can track HTTP exchanges pretty well using Chrome or Firefox developer tools - part of browser. That should give some hints.

Comment: _"but my question is not site's specific"_ - Different sites have different ways of detecting these kind of things. Some requires you to add a proper user agent with the request. Some sites uses CSRF etc. There are many ways to skin this cat. Try and Google on "How to detect bots" or similar and you will most likely find some guides about this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm following the directions on the site's robots.txt file but still being blocked. I will do some research on that Magnus. Thanks.